# With HighCharts, how can I have the same tooltip formatter as my y axis

Tags: highcharts

With HighCharts, is there a way for my tooltip formatter to use the selected y axis formatter? In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p6591xj3/2/), I've added a y axis formatter (divide by thousand), but the tooltip contents remain unformatted.

Edit: I have a dynamic number of y-axis and series.

```
.highcharts({
    tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#AAA',
      formatter: function(e){
         // do some magic here
      }
    },
    yAxis: [
        {
      id: 'score',
        min: 0,
        max: 10000,
        title: 'Score',
        labels: {
            formatter: function(e){
            return e.value/1000 + 'k';
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    series: [{
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Laurel',
        data: [1000,2000,3000,8000,5000],
        yAxis: 'score'
    },
    {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Yanni',
        data: [3000,7000,3000,2000,1000],
        yAxis: 'score'
    }]
});
```

Comment: If you just want to format the tooltip using a formatter, @Core972 has posted the answer. If your question is if you can reuse or use the same formatter for labels and tooltip, then the answer is no. You could only pass the actual value to a function that does the same thing to it.

Comment: Ok, didn't quite make myself clear on that. I might have multiple y-axes, each with a different formatter - kilometers and minutes plotted on the same chart. From the tooltip formatter, I know the name of the series. Might be able to do some hack there...

Comment: You have some options then. You can include a custom flag per series, and format the tooltip/axis based on the custom flag. You can also of course match by name. Alternatively, you can also set tooltip formatter per series (and make functions that can be reused for many series), API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: I edited my answer with multiple `yAxis`

Comment: I managed to find an okay solution. Put the formatting function on the series also, can be found on  // this.series.options - http://jsfiddle.net/p6591xj3/17/

Answer (score 1):

You must set the `tooltip formatter` [Api](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) like that :

```
tooltip:{
  ...
  formatter: function(){
    var text = '';
    if(this.series.index == 0) {
        text = this.series.name + ' : ' + this.y/1000 + 'k';
    } else {
        text = '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b> : ' + this.y ;
    }
    return text;
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/p6591xj3/8/)

**Edit for multiple yAxis**

Comment: Ok for one y-axis, but I might have several. Any way of using the actual y axis formatter?